Excel Power Query - Populate empty values in table
I’m a newbie in Excel Power queries (M) and would appreciate some assistance. I have a table with the structure below. I would like to populate a column called “Daily Wage”, which is = “3 month Salary” divided by 90 (days in 3 months). The difficulty is that:

on Fridays, given the weekend, the ‘Daily Wage’ will cover 3 days, so it will be 3x the other work days

Secondly, the “3M Salary” is missing in certain rows. In that case, we can proxy it with the person’s previous 3 month salary (look for prior rows for that person until the 3m salary is found)


Example Table:



Date
Name
3 Month Salary
Daily Wage




2 Jan 2024
John
10,000
?


3 Jan 2024
John

?


4 Jan 2024
John

?



Thank you!
Struggled when the 3 Month Salary is missing

let
Source = YourSourceHere,

AddDailyWage = Table.AddColumn(Source", "Daily Wage", each 
    let
        currentSalary = [#"3 Month Salary"],
        previousSalary = try Table.SelectRows(
            Source, (row) => row[Name] = [Name] and row[Date] < [Date])[#"3 Month Salary"]{0} otherwise null,
        salary = if currentSalary = null then previousSalary else currentSalary,
        dailyWage = salary / 90,
        isFriday = Date.DayOfWeek([Date]) = 4,
        adjustedWage = if isFriday then dailyWage * 3 else dailyWage
    in
        adjustedWage
)
 in
     AddDailyWage


Thank you very much. I have a question. Would this line always pick up the last salary it can find or do we have to make sure the dates are in descending order first?      previousSalary = try Table.SelectRows(
Source, (row) => row[Name] = [Name] and row[Date] < [Date])[#"3 Month Salary"]{0} otherwise null,

@BellaGrubb - why don't you test it to see how it works.

@MichalRosa I suggest you use the optional FirstDayofWeek argument for Date.DayOfWeek. Otherwise 4 may not always be Friday.  In the United States, for example 4 would be Thursday since our culture starts the week on Sunday.

Here's another method, which includes:

Grouping by Name in case your real data includes more than one person
Using FillDown to fill in the missing salary numbers.

Original Data

M Code
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Salary"]}[Content],

//Since these are salaries, will use the Currency Type
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{
        "Date", type date}, {"Name", type text}, {"3 Month Salary", Currency.Type}}),

//Fill Down the "Name" column in case some are missing
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Name"}),

//Group by Name to do the calculations
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Name"}, {
        {"Add Daily", (t)=>
            let 

            //Fill in the missing 3 month salary using Fill Down
                #"Fill 3 Month" = Table.FillDown(t, {"3 Month Salary"}),

            //Add the daily wage with test for Friday
                #"Add Daily Wage" = Table.AddColumn(#"Fill 3 Month", "Daily Wage", 
                    each 
                        if Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Sunday)=Day.Friday 
                            then [#"3 Month Salary"] / 30
                            else [#"3 Month Salary"] / 90)
            in #"Add Daily Wage"        
        ,type table [Date=nullable date, Name=nullable text, 3 Month Salary=Currency.Type, Daily Wage=Currency.Type]}}),

//Remove unneeded column and expand the grouped table
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Name"}),
    #"Expanded Add Daily" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Add Daily", 
        {"Date", "Name", "3 Month Salary", "Daily Wage"})
in
    #"Expanded Add Daily"

Results

You should test to see which is more efficient on your actual data.
For fun, I have added a formula solution to my answer which requires 365 to run. Again, testing solutions for efficiency in your particular environment is suggested
=LET(
    d, Salary,
    fd, MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(d),
        COLUMNS(d),
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                INDEX(d, r, c) = "",
                LOOKUP(
                    2,
                    1 / LEN(INDEX(d, SEQUENCE(r), c)),
                    INDEX(d, SEQUENCE(r), c)
                ),
                INDEX(d, r, c)
            )
        )
    ),
    ds, MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(fd),
        1,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                WEEKDAY(INDEX(fd, r, 1), 3) > 4,
                "??",
                IF(
                    WEEKDAY(INDEX(fd, r, 1), 3) = 4,
                    INDEX(fd, r, 3) / 30,
                    INDEX(fd, r, 3) / 90
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(HSTACK(Salary[#Headers], {"Daily Salary"}), HSTACK(fd, ds))
)

Example

